# Is there any way I can create a System::Type object representing a DateTime object without a DateTime object?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Wanted for property grid, in the PropertyType function of the class derived from PropertyDescriptor, but I don't want an actual DateTime object - I'll just convert it to and from String in SetValue and GetValue.

Comment: err... theoretically, I suppose.  But why?

Comment: typeof(DateTime)? I don't really get what you're after, but that'll give you a System.Type for DateTime

Comment: for my property grid - I want to store all the info in Strings - even dates - so i can write to a file quickly, but i want there to be a datetime picker.

Comment: I'm using c++ - doesn't recognize typeof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type the following

```
Type t = typeof(DateTime);
```

C++/CLI equivalent as asked for in comments

```
Type^ t = DateTime::typeid;
```

Comment: I'm using c++ - doesn't recognize typeof

Comment: @Elliot, added the C++/CLI equivalent.